# RubyMine Cucumber Step Definitions default format I want Cucumber Expressions NOT regular expressions

Tags: format, definition, rubymine

I've got RubyMine version 2023.1.5 and Cucumber version 8.0.0

When I create a step in the feature file and use the Create Step Definition hover button to create the Step Definitions the definition is created with regular expressions e.g.

> Given(/^don't want this$/) do

But I want the default format to be Cucumber Expressions like

> Given('I want this format') do

but I cannot find out how to get RubyMine to use this format as default, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, it's not possible, so please add your vote to the corresponding [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-22518/Option-for-create-step-definition-to-create-new-Cucumber-Expressions-instead-of-regex).